# How to compile libhdf5_fortran.a library file?

Tags: compilation, fortran, hdf5

I downloaded latest hdf5-1.14.0.tar.gz. After extraction, I configure as

```
FC=/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.1.0/linux/bin/intel64/ifort ./configure --enable-fortran
```

after make, I can find

```
libhdf5.a  libhdf5.la  libhdf5.settings  libhdf5.so  libhdf5.so.310  libhdf5.so.310.0.0
```

but what I need is `libhdf5_fortran.a`. But the closest file I can find is `libhdf5_fortran.la` under `fortran/src`. So how to generate `libhdf5_fortran.a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting up the Intel compiler correctly. You should run the setvars script to set up *all* the required paths, and not just provide the absolute path to the compiler. If I do as you have the configure fails with the following

```
checking if Fortran compiler supports intrinsic SIZEOF... no
checking if Fortran compiler supports intrinsic C_SIZEOF... no
checking if Fortran compiler supports intrinsic STORAGE_SIZE... no
configure: error: Fortran compiler requires either intrinsic functions SIZEOF or STORAGE_SIZE
```

However if I set up the compiler as recommended and run the configure via

```
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/Downloads/hdf5-1.14.0$ . /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh 
 
:: initializing oneAPI environment ...
   bash: BASH_VERSION = 5.0.17(1)-release
   args: Using "$@" for setvars.sh arguments: 
:: advisor -- latest
:: ccl -- latest
:: clck -- latest
:: compiler -- latest
:: dal -- latest
:: debugger -- latest
:: dev-utilities -- latest
:: dnnl -- latest
:: dpcpp-ct -- latest
:: dpl -- latest
:: inspector -- latest
:: intelpython -- latest
:: ipp -- latest
:: ippcp -- latest
:: ipp -- latest
:: itac -- latest
:: mkl -- latest
:: mpi -- latest
:: tbb -- latest
:: vpl -- latest
:: vtune -- latest
:: oneAPI environment initialized ::
 
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/Downloads/hdf5-1.14.0$ FC=ifort ./configure --enable-fortran
```

the configure works and after a

```
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/Downloads/hdf5-1.14.0$ make -j 4
```

it compiles correctly and gives the file you are after:

```
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/Downloads/hdf5-1.14.0$ find . -name libhdf5_fortran.a -print
./fortran/src/.libs/libhdf5_fortran.a
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually, I set up ifort correctly and compile correctly. But I never thought `libhdf5_fortran.a` is under a hidden folder .libs

Comment: Yes, it is a bizarre place to put it. Possibly it is waiting for a subsequent `make install` but I'm not at my computer currently